# why does Vector2 say it is float when it is not?

Tags: python, math, vector, pygame

ok, I want to draw a circle with startpoint, and endpoint coordinates, startpoint and endpoint are both Vector2

```
startpoint = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)
endpoint = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)

def redraw_game_window():
    win.fill((0,0,0))
    line_one = line(startpoint, endpoint, (255,0,0), 2)
    line_one.draw(win)

    print("EndPoint: ",endpoint)
    print("StartPoint: ",startpoint)
    pygame.draw.circle(win, (0,0,255), startpoint, 3, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(win, (0,255,0), endpoint, 3, 0)


    pygame.display.update()
```

the "pygame.draw.circle..." are the problem, the error is

```
  File "lines.py", line 43, in redraw_game_window
    pygame.draw.circle(win, (0,0,255), startpoint, 3, 0)
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
```

and when I enter any other coordinates, like this:

```
pygame.draw.circle(win, (0,0,255), (500, 250), 3, 0)
pygame.draw.circle(win, (0,255,0), (100, 147), 3, 0)
```

then it works fine, like why ? why Vector2 doesnt work
(here is full code)

```
#Lines
import pygame
import os
import sys
import random
import math

#Init the game
pygame.init()

#Display
win_width = 800
win_height = 600
win = pygame.display.set_mode((win_width, win_height))

#Display settings
pygame.display.set_caption("lines")

#Variables
startpoint = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)
endpoint = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)

class line():
    def __init__(self, start, end, color, thickness):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.color = color
        self.thickness = thickness

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.line(win, self.color, self.start, self.end, self.thickness)


def redraw_game_window():
    win.fill((0,0,0))
    line_one = line(startpoint, endpoint, (255,0,0), 2)
    line_one.draw(win)

    print("EndPoint: ",endpoint)
    print("StartPoint: ",startpoint)
    pygame.draw.circle(win, (0,0,255), startpoint, 3, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(win, (0,255,0), endpoint, 3, 0)


    pygame.display.update()

run = True
while run:
    #Quit event
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                mousex, mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                startpoint = pygame.math.Vector2(mousex, mousey)
                print("LEFT CLICK")

            if event.button == 3:
                mousex, mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                endpoint = pygame.math.Vector2(mousex, mousey)
                print("RIGHT CLICK")

    #Redraw game window
    redraw_game_window()

pygame.quit()
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: The x and y component of `Vector2` are always of type `float`. You have to use `(round(startpoint.x), round(startpoint.y))`

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Answer (score 1):

The x and y component of `Vector2` are always of type `float`. You have convert the to a tuple with to integral components. Use [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) to convert the coordinates e.g: `(round(startpoint.x), round(startpoint.y))`

I recommend to write a function:

```py
def V2ToInt(v):
    return (round(v.x), round(v.y))
```

Use it like this:

```py
pygame.draw.circle(win, (0,0,255), V2ToInt(startpoint), 3, 0)
pygame.draw.circle(win, (0,255,0), V2ToInt(endpoint), 3, 0)
```

---

alternatively you can use a [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-lambda-expr) expression:

```py
v2ToInt = lambda v: (round(v.x), round(v.y)) 
pygame.draw.circle(win, (0,0,255), v2ToInt(startpoint), 3, 0)
pygame.draw.circle(win, (0,255,0), v2ToInt(endpoint), 3, 0)
```